# Conditional CSS rules with less, based on variable

Tags: css, less

The variable can take percentage or px values, like:

`@some-var: 50px;` or `@some-var: 46%;`

How can I define a certain set of CSS rules if the value is in pixels, and a different set of rules if the values is in percentages?

Is there something like

```
if(isValueInPixels(@some-var)){

  // css rules here


}else{

  // other rules here
}
```

?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you can use something that they call **Guarded Mixins**.

Try something like this...

```
.mixin (@a) when (ispixel(@a)) {
 /* ... your pixel specific logic ... */
}
.mixin (@a) when (ispercentage(@a)) {
 /* ... your percentage specific logic ... */
}

.coolStuff {
 .mixin(50px);
 .mixin(50%);
}
```

See the **Guarded Mixins** at http://lesscss.org/

Comment: I found what I needed in addition to this answer was a default which is possible using `default()` function. From the docs at http://lesscss.org/features/#mixin-guards-feature-conditional-mixins `.mixin (@a) when (default()) { ... }`

Answer (score 7):

As Adam Spicer noted the **Guarded Mixins** are your best solution.
However, LESS now offers a solution to group multiple guards, which will allow this to be accomplished with a single mixin.
http://lesscss.org/features/#css-guards-feature

For Example:

```
.mixin(@a){
  & when (ispixel(@a)){
    //logic
  }
  & when (ispercentage(@a)){
    //logic
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
selector{
  .mixin(50px);
  .mixin(46%);
}
```